# How do I tell TeamCity to get the sources needed by a solution and not just a TFS server path?

Tags: tfs, teamcity

I want TeamCity to download the latest version from TFS based on a given Visual Studio solution not just a path on the TFS server. 
The build server should not get files on TFS that we forgot to add to the correct solution.

Comment: To be clear, you want to tell TeamCity "Get everything that's added to this Solution". Because your last sentence seems to contradict that... if you forgot to add something to the Solution, you need to fix that. Whether you use a TFS path or Solution won't help.

Comment: Thank you. You made it understandable. I tried to make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Specify solution as build file
   Goto TeamCity administration -> Configuration -> Runner (MSBuild) -> Build file path
2. VCS Root settings -> Client Mapping: specify from which folders TC should copy files

Comment: Could be I missunderstand you. But I read this as the build server will retrieve all files from a given folder, is it so? I want all files spesified by a given solution or project file(s).

Comment: Here is should be specified all folders which are involved somehow by solution, so it could be referenced libraries or external resources, all these folders should be in client mappings to be correctly picked up whilst solution build

Comment: But this will still result in a "get" from source control of the entire TFS path. It sounds like Nasit wants a streamlined "get".

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to configure your build [Checkout Mode](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/VCS+Checkout+Mode) to *not check out files automatically*. Then, write a custom build step that will perform the checkout for you. But, it looks like checking out just the solution is a [tricky problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204/vs2008-tfs-get-latest-of-solution-from-command-line-or-macro) itself. You'll probably want to write a custom MSBuild step (possibly writing a custom .NET task) or use PowerShell.

You'll have to remember to reference *every file* from inside the solution, like your library dependencies, or the checkout won't actually get everything it needs.

Looking at all this fuss, I would look harder at *why* you want this behavior and see if you can restructure your solution/vcs paths to avoid the problem all together.